# Decode escaped Url without using HttpUtility.UrlDecode

Tags: .net, url

Is there any function that converts an escaped Url string to its unescaped form? `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` can do that job but I don't want to add a reference to `System.Web.dll`. Since my app is not a web application, I don't want to add a dependency for only using a function in an assembly.

**UPDATE:** Check [Rick Strahl's blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/617930.aspx) about the same issue.

Comment: Rick Strahl's post is a must read - it contains the necessary background and an in depth analysis of the different solutions the .NET framework offers (or doesn't offer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decode a URL parameter using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**EDIT:** Use the static method **`Uri.UnescapeDataString()`** to decode your URLs:

*Encoded:* `http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fsearch%3fhl%3den%26q%3dsomething%20%2323%26btnG%3dGoogle%2bSearch%26aq%3df%26oq%3d`

*Decoded:* `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=something #23&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=`

Comment: this dosen't to work for me it just returns the original string pass to the `Uri.UnescapeDataString(myurl)`

Comment: Beware: This doesn't work for plus signs -  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx I'm still looking for a better method.

Comment: @Chris: Rick Strahl built a utility class around `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` that handles the `+` signs correctly. See [his blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/617930.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: Four years later -- I _think_ `UnescapeDataString` handles plus signs now.
https://repl.it/repls/MildGlossyPorts

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or later, you can use [WebUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode) which works with client profile and also correctly processes plus signs.

Comment: FYI both of these links are dead.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft killed a lot of old links, I've updated my answer with the current one.

Answer (score 4):

Re not loading System.Web.dll - as others have noted, it isn't worth getting excited unless you know that you need to deal with clients that might not have it ("client profile", "compact framework", "micro framework", "silverlight").

Re space; it won't be a lot really; note that .NET assemblies are JITted on a method-by-method basis, so there won't be any significant overhead just from using a few methods.

The real issue (IMO) is your level of confidence that the client has System.Web.dll; if you are happy that they are using the full framework, then just go for it.

Comment: System.Web.dll is *very* heavy, with *noticeable* startup impact.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist roll on vNext, eh?

Comment: Has nothing else come along in 7 years? I mean, its going to have to for vNext.

Answer (score 2):

@Smith
I was having the save problem. No changes or just further jumbling.

After testing many things I noticed a test string did decode. Ultimately I had to create a new empty string,  set it's value to the encoded string then run `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString` on the new string. For some reason I had to run the decode and unescape in the order I mentioned. Bizarre.

I solved it with something like this.

```
Dim strEncoded as string="http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fsearch%3fhl%3den%26q%3dsomething%20%2323%26btnG%3dGoogle%2bSearch%26aq%3df%26oq%3d"

Dim strDecoded as string = ""
strDecoded = strEncoded
strDecoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strDecoded)
strDecoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(strDecoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ACE team have an extended (and better) version of decode, in the [Anti-XSS library](http://blogs.msdn.com/ace_team/archive/2006/11/20/microsoft-anti-cross-site-scripting-library-v1-5-is-done.aspx). However I'm not sure if it just passes through.

(I don't see why you're that worried about the dependency on System.web.dll to be honest)

Comment: The reason is that I don't want to load a rather large DLL into my memory space for the sake of only one method call. It would be good if someone points an implementation (probably uses Regex) that I can copy/paste into my project.

Comment: A regex solution is not going to be enough; decoding is *hard*.

If you're really worried then, *cough*, reflector.

Have you actually looked at the memory cost of loading the assembly? It's probably not as large as you think.

Comment: Note that different framework versions (esp. "client profile") are a valid reason to avoid it - but not worth getting *too* excited over it ;-p

Comment: Actually, the AntiXss library does not provide the decoding methods, only encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a HUGE dependency on the .NET framework, CLR etal.  So, in fact, you already have an indirect dependency on System.Web.DLL; your application CAN NOT RUN without its presence on the local machine.

And you're worried about memory?  Do you have memory issues?  If you have memory issues so extreme you can't load a couple KBs of DLL into your app's memory, then why are you coding .NET?  Or are you just prematurely optimizing?

So don't worry about it.

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect; "client profile", "cf" and "silverlight" will all lack System.Web.dll; "client profile" is a version of regular .NET, so is the most striking.

Comment: @marc iirc when this was answered the client profiles weren't released/commonly known about.  Second, he doesn't say what kind of app, and in fact from the way he asks the question its obvious that it IS an option to reference system.web.dll.  Otherwise the question is moot.  So my assertation is most likely correct.  Nyah.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little understanding of why it's different.  One converts to uppercase and one converts to lowercase.   So the decode is specific to the type of encode.

**System.Net.WebUtility** (Internal) **+ 65**:

```
private static char IntToHex(int n)
{
    if (n <= 9)
        return (char) (n + 48);
    else
        return (char) (n - 10 + 65);
}
```

**System.Web.Util.HttpEncoderUtility** (Internal) - **+ 97**

```
public static char IntToHex(int n)
{
    if (n <= 9)
        return (char) (n + 48);
    else
        return (char) (n - 10 + 97);
}
```

**Example**:

```
var test1 = WebUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.test.com/?param1=22&param2=there@is<a space");
var test2 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.test.com/?param1=22&param2=there@is<a space");
```

**Response**:

```
test1 -> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fparam1%3D22%26param2%3Dthere%40is%3Ca+space
test2 -> http%3a%2f%2fwww.test.com%2f%3fparam1%3d22%26param2%3dthere%40is%3ca+space
```

[More information....](https://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/05/21/beware-webutility-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode/)

Answer (score 0):

In Android this fixed the issue, It took me few hours to figure out, I hope I am saving your time now

```
val objectRequest = GetObjectRequest(s3Uri.bucket, S3HttpUtils.urlDecode(s3Uri.key))
```

Answer (score -3):

`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode` is also working on .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

Comment: Url endcoding/decoding != Html encoding/decoding.