# How can I decode a URL escape string in C#?

Tags: c#, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to decode url param with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-to-decode-url-param-with-c)

I want to change all those %20 ect. to spaces ect.

Comment: Same as [
how to decode url param with c#
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-to-decode-url-param-with-c).

Comment: can youa add information about what kind of application you are using? Is it Webforms or ASP.Net MVC application?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[HttpUtility.UrlDecode(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) and [HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode.aspx)

Comment: WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str) is better solution because HttpUtility doesn't decode "&apos;" symbol.. I don't know why..

Comment: The question was regarding URL's not HTML.

Comment: @freedwall Could you provide an example of the string that is not decoding correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Server.UrlDecode(string);
```