# got a strange error today with SPUtility.Redirect

Tags: c#, redirect

Got a strange error today with SPUtility.Redirect. I am using it in one of my webparts, there IS Column field url enter url and trying to redirect

my Current Url:-http://pc9:9001/Surveys/Lists/Single%20Q%202%20Choice

After Past Url in Clolumn click on save

Click on redirect button it return new 
url:http://pc9:9001/Surveys/Lists/Single%2520Q%25202%2520Choice

Ith Adding 25 No Extra in Url, so How To Remove 25 number From URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these %20 and %25 characters are caused by encoding urls. to remove them just decode the url.

check these :

[How can I decode a URL escape string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792458/how-can-i-decode-a-url-escape-string-in-c)

[How do I decode a URL parameter using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)

Comment: Line Work For My Requirment :->                                                            string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Url);