# how to delete an azure blob with encoded name?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have bunch of blobs on azure storage which follow name in following pattern: `<someName>_DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`. When I fetch the blobs using `container.ListBlobs()` the blob Uri looks like this: `<someName>__11%252f3%252f2014+10%253a00%253a00+PM+%252b00%253a00+%252b00%253a00`.

If you look closely, `%25` becomes `%` when encoded once and `%2f` becomes `:`. So it looks like the Uri goes through double encoding.

When I try to get hold of this blob, it doesn't work. Here is the code snippet:

```
BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("myPrefix", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 10, null, null, null);
var list = resultSegment.Results.Select(x => x.Uri.ToString().Split('/').Last());
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blob.FetchAttributes();
foreach (var element in list)
        {
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(element);

            blob.FetchAttributes();
            var t = blob.Metadata;
        }
```

Any Idea how do I encode the URL before trying to access it?

Note: I use latest azure storage library

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c  You probably only need to decode once, but try twice if it doesn't work.  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx for non-ASP.net answer)

Comment: tried WebUtility.UrlDecode(WebUtility.UrlDecode(blobName)), WebUtility.UrlDecode(blobName), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(blobName) etc. none of them work. Not so sure how blob name is represented internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to get a blob reference, we can just convert the ListBlob result to `ICloudBlob` and call delete on it. Here is the code:

```
var l= resultSegment.Results.Select(x => x as ICloudBlob);
foreach (var cloudBlob in l)
        {
            cloudBlob.Delete();
        }
```