# string replace for multiple characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

blaBla\John.Boy

```
string _uName = id.Name.Split('\\')[1];
string _userName = _uName.Replace('.', ' ');
```

will return: "John Boy"

I want to use the replace, but with a replaceAll.

I have `string url="Account/WindowsLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMemberPages%2fcustomerDataStorePortal.aspx"`

from this I want to create `string NewUrl="/MemberPages/customerDataStorePortal.aspx"`

so get data after the '=' and replace '%2F' with '/'

so far:

```
string redirectUrl1 = redirectUrlOLD.Split('=')[1];
string redirectUrl = redirectUrl1.Replace('%2F', '/');
```

is flagging %2F as too many characters

Answer (score 5):

`""` is for a string

`''` represents a single char

This is the way that you want to go

```
redirectUrl1.Replace("%2F", "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string redirectUrl = redirectUrl1.Replace("%2F", "/");
```

Use `"` instead `'`

Comment: It might be helpful to explain *why* a single quote is different in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("Account/WindowsLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMemberPages%2fcustomerDataStorePortal.aspx");
```

Also see the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Uri` class and it's [`UnescapeDataString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string returnUrlParam = "?ReturnUrl=";
int paramIndex = url.IndexOf(returnUrlParam);
if (paramIndex >= 0)
{
    string param = url.Substring(paramIndex + returnUrlParam.Length);
    string newUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(param); // "/MemberPages/customerDataStorePortal.aspx"
}
```

If you can add a reference to `System.Web` you can use `System.Web.HttpUtility`:

```
string queryString = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?') + 1);
var queryParams = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
string newUrl = queryParams["ReturnUrl"]; // "/MemberPages/customerDataStorePortal.aspx"
```

Note that you cannot add `System.Web` if your target-framework is: framework *x* **client profile**(default for winforms, wpf etc.). You need to select the full framework.

Answer (score 0):

Along with using a string replacement instead of a char replacement, you can chain your methods together.  Also it looks like you're replacing an uppercase `F` when the string contains lowercase `f`

```
string redirectUrl = url.Split('=')[1].Replace("%2f", "/");
```