# Encoding.utf8 converting comma to some special character in c#

Tags: c#, c++, utf-8, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

My device send data on eventhub using Encoding.UTF8 in c++ language.My receiver is written in c# .While receiving data from Eventhub (**string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());**) comma is replaced with **%2c**

- **My eventhub message is** DeviceID,Temprature,Humidity\nfdf5d821-c490-4405-b84c-171b478666d1,55,65
- **but string return in c# is**

  DeviceID%2CTemprature%2CHumidity%0Afdf5d821%2Dc490%2D4405%2Db84c%2D171b478
  666d1%2C55%2C65
- **My first Question** is how to receive data as it is as i send to eventhub without special character in c#
- When Stream analytic run so it read the data from eventhub or not?

Comment: This is not about UTF8, but it´s URL encoded (at least something similar). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c

Answer (score 2):

You can decode url by using [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) or [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)

for example

```
string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url)
```