# "Decode" special characters: %c3 -> Ö, %20 -> Space, etc

Tags: c#

I want to implement a little Dropdown that will show Items that I searched for in a folder.

So, the problem is that I'm German and we have characters like Ä, Ö, Ü etc.

These characters are shown in a strange way. For example, the char Ö is "%c3". Also, spaces are shown as "%20".

Is there a simple way to change them without the `string.Replace` function?

My code:

```
try
{
    string dirPath = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + 
        "\\Arma 3 - Other Profiles");

    List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));

    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dir);
        MessageBox.Show(dir);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dir.ToString());
    }
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
}
catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some code how you are filling dropdown currently?

Comment: yes because it sounds like you are using a UrlEncode mechanism somewhere...

Comment: Are these URL encoded strings?  `%20` is the URL encoded space character at least.  Have you tried decoding this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c?

Comment: I Added my Code above

Comment: Don't call `UrlDecode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dir);
```

you UrlDecode the string and then throw away the result. You probably wanted to write:

```
dir = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dir);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myString)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This wasnt really helpfull. Its still in this way!