# How to UrlDecode without having System.Web dll in c#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting, urldecode

I'm about to create a self-hosted Web API application, and somewhere I need to URL Decode the input. But I truly don't want to add a reference to System.Web.dll, because AMAIK, it's a heavy DLL and one of the main reasons of getting far from ASP.NET and IIS.

If I'm right, and I don't add a reference to System.Web, then how can I URL Decode effectively without bugs?

Comment: Please look at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

//.Net 4.0+

you can use  **WebUtility.UrlDecode()**. It is not part of system.web.

And you can see this blog:
[Html and Uri String Encoding without System.Web](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Feb/05/Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb)