# parsing string to model

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Have this :

```
 HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
 string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

then in this jsonContent :

> ID=1234&toName=&fromId=49gjgijl7a4in

I am trying to parse in model :

```
 Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(jsonContent);
```

But it throws an exception :

> Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 0, position 0

Any idea ?

Edit :

My client side logic :

```
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"toId", obj.toId},
                    {"toName", obj.toName},
                    {"fromId", obj.fromId},
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: That is not Json.

Comment: If it is not `JSON` why do you use `JsonConvert`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decode a URL parameter using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse parameters from uri query string, use this from `System.Web.HttpUtility`

```
var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content);
var id = query.Get("ID");
var toName = query.Get("toName");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data as `Json` objects use this code (client-side):

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var jsonObj = (dynamic)new JsonObject();
jsonObj.toId = obj.toId;
jsonObj.toName = obj.toName;
jsonObj.fromId = obj.fromId;

var content = new StringContent(jsonObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Then you can use `JsonConvert` as in your question.

**OR**

If you want send data as query string but then use as `Json`:

```
var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(jsonContent);
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    dict.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]));
```

Then you can use `JsonConvert` to deserialize it to your model.

**OR**

If you don't want to change client-side logic:

```
var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(jsonContent);

YourModel model = new YourModel()
{
    Id = dict.Get("ID"]),
    ToName = dict.Get("toName"),
    FromId = dict.Get("fromId")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Json Content Should be like this. Check you content

```
{ 
"ID":1234,
 "toName":"",
"fromId": "49gjgijl7a4in"
}
```

Comment: I am creating that way. But how to convert it into model after getting the content from headers ?

Comment: You can try this method if you have model:

TryUpdateModel<modelType>(requestContent );

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

//you can split your jsonContent then you use the code
string[] paramsArrs = jsonContent.Split('&');`
```