# How to keep special character string in php $_POST?

Tags: php, rest, header, request

I'm trying a simple post request in php with rest client, but the form will contain special characters.

raw headers:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

raw payload:

```
login=teste@teste.com&pwd=pmWkWSBCL51Bfkhn79xPuKBKHz//H6B+mY6G9/eieuM=
```

php:

```
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
```

Output:

```
"pmWkWSBCL51Bfkhn79xPuKBKHz\/\/H6B mY6G9\/eieuM="
```

How to keep original string in php $_POST?

Comment: What you want..you are not clear to me?

Comment: Do this `$pwd = str_replace(' ','+',stripslashes($_POST['pwd']));`

Comment: Basically keep the slashes and plus.

Comment: Maybe base64 encode the `pwd` before send via POST.

Comment: Try this ,I think you are looking for this $pwd =  mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);

Comment: $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']) not works. Two parameters expecteds, $link,$string;

Comment: You can use `url_encode()` and `url_decode()`

Comment: Xorifelse..  Yes.. Url_encode works.
login=teste%40teste.com&pwd=pmWkWSBCL51Bfkhn79xPuKBKHz%2F%2FH6B%2BmY6G9%2FeieuM%3D

Comment: How to use encode payload in my request using restSharp in C#? Any idea?

Comment: There is a [search feature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1405048/4982088) available on this website.