# How extract Specific names from url?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, extract

I already have Listbox full with URLs like this I convert them to String

http://example.com/1392/Music/1392/Shahrivar/21/Avicii%20-%20True/01.%20Avicii%20Ft.%20Aloe%20Blacc%20-%20Wake%20Me%20Up%20(CDQ)%20%5b320%5d.mp3
and I wanna extract for example on this link Name of Song:  "Avicii Ft Aloe Blacc -Wake Me Up " I'm using c# I already extract links from a web page and now I only need to extract names from links. thanks already for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)?

Comment: isn't duplicate I already spent hours searching here and other websites and I didn't find nothing

Comment: @elmissouriabdlouahed It's  a duplicate. You want to unescape a URL and parse a path.

Comment: What have you tried so far? is the Url always in the same Format?

Comment: @EdPlunkett if is duplicate please provide me with post because i search lot and i didn't find here

Comment: @moi_meme no isn't same format

Comment: @elmissouriabdlouahed I told you what to search for. Search for "unescape URL C#". Then once you have it unescaped (that changes the `%` stuff to regular characters), you want to search for "split path C#" or "parse path C#". I'm not being *too* hard on you -- it's pretty easy once you know what you're looking for.

Comment: ok, thanks, @EdPlunkett I appreciate the help

Comment: string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(txt_url.Text);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(decodedUrl);
            lbl_name.Text = fileName; i use this i decode url and after i use whats u told me to get name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the structure of the URL you are scraping you should be able to break-off the useless part of the string.

For example, if you know that the URL follows the form: 
http://example.com/1392/Music/1392/Shahrivar/21/{Artist}-{Album}/{Track Information}

Roughly, I think the following would allow you to extract the information you want from a single link:

```
void Main (string[] args) 
{
  var example = @"http://example.com/1392/Music/1392/Shahrivar/21/Avicii%20-%20True/01.%20Avicii%20Ft.%20Aloe%20Blacc%20-%20Wake%20Me%20Up%20(CDQ)%20%5b320%5d.mp3";

    var parts = example.split('/');
    var album = parts[7];
    var trackInfo = parts[8];

    var trackParts = trackInfo.split('-');
    var artist = trackParts[0];
    var trackTitle = trackParts[1];

    Console.WriteLine(trackTitle);
}
```

Here I am splitting the URL by '/', which is a messy solution, but for a simple case, it works. Then I am finding the index within the tokenized string where the desired information can be found. once I have the track information, I know the convention is to separate the Artist from the Title by a '-', so I split again and then have both artist and title.

You can refactor this into a method which takes the URL, and returns an object containing the Artist and song title. After that, you might want to use a string.Replace on the '%20' with ' '.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://example.com/1392/Music/1392/Shahrivar/21/Avicii%20-%20True/01.%20Avicii%20Ft.%20Aloe%20Blacc%20-%20Wake%20Me%20Up%20(CDQ)%20%5b320%5d.mp3";

            var uri = new Uri (url);

            string[] segments = uri.Segments.Select (x => WebUtility.UrlDecode (x).TrimEnd ('/')).ToArray ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `HttpUtility.DecodeUrl`. This function will decode HTML special chars, leaving a plain string to work with. You can then simply split by `/`.