# How to pass string with special characters to Server side function

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a basic app service that creates a title. When my clientside page passes the parameter values to my server side function with special characters, question marks are appearing.

May I ask how do I fix this?

My current code.

index.js

```
var title = "Búsq"
titleService.CreateTitle(title).success(function (data) {
    vm.title= data;
});
```

TitleAppService.cs

```
public string CreateTitle(string title)
{
    // title is received here as B�sq <- how do I resolve this, it should be Búsq
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that the `title` parameter is passes in the entry path (as a `query string` parameter)? Because if so - it should be encoded first

Comment: @ymz any tips on encoding it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How did you store index.js on the disk? Try to store index.js using utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `title` parameters is passed as a part of the url it should be encoded **BEFORE** sending to the server. In some platforms the value should be decoded on server-side

**Client-Side encoding - JS** (From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))

```
titleService.CreateTitle(encodeURIComponent(title)).success(function (data) {
    vm.title= data;
});
```

**Server-Side decoding - C#** (Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405065/4062197))

```
public string CreateTitle(string title)
{
    title = Server.UrlDecode(title);
}
```