# MS Teams Bot & MS Graph meetings

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

We can use this GET method to get a meeting object from Join Url Address!

When i try that from the graph explorer its all working ! but when i try that from .net SDK its giving below error

> "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'JoinWebUrl' on type 'Default.<>f__AnonymousType0_1Of<>f__AnonymousType1_2OfString_String

This is my code :

```js
string body = string.Format("JoinWebUrl eq '{0}'", joinWeb);
var meetingTest = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings
                .Request()
                .Filter(body)
                .GetAsync();
```

am I doing it wrong?

I'm using the graph beta SDK and I test this query in graph explorer it's working but not with SDK it gives me an error

Comment: So this question isn't really about Teams, is it?

Comment: its about MS Teams bot

Comment: The reason behind this is the url need to be properly encoded to filter it. Please encode the whole filter like this `$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fl%2Fmeetup-join%2F19%3Ameeting_OTg1YjAxNmYtN2EyZC00YWI0LWI1ZDMtMjVkZDljOTYzMTEz%40thread.v2%2F0%3Fcontext%3D%7B%22Tid%22%3A%22363147dc-b3be-41a7-af56-f673893ef5a7%22%2C%22Oid%22%3A%221ab4e76f-5f52-44b8-8a72-7d03c05e6ff4%22%7D%27`. Remember one thing, when you get the joinweburl, context parameter is already encoded. So try avoiding it or decode that part and encode the whole url and then apply the call.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity actully i dident tried that how can i do that ? i mean any where to encode urls proberly ?

Comment: You can look into this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp) for Encoding and for Decoding look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

I created a new meeting in outlook canlender, and I got a meeting Join Url Address like this:
[image]

Then I tried the api you provided and got the same response. At first I `tried to remove the filter parameter`, I think 'filter' is an optional parameter, so if the parameter was removed, I would get correct answer, but it didn't work. I got a response like this:
[image]

```
This error resulted from api permission:
```

[image]

Then I change the url, `replace me to users/{userId}`, but I got a `response like 'app can not on behalf of the user`.

I googled that error, and get [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy), it describes the fact `that applications should be allowed to access online meetings on behalf of a user`. So I [install Microsoft Teams PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-install), [connect to Skype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-skype-for-business-online-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide), and [add policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy).

Following the steps above, I can call the api successfully.
[image]

Comment: i used it from the Graph explorer its working well ! but from Graph .net Beta SDK i get this error

Comment: You mean ,it's ok when you calling the api directly, but get error message like you posted in the question when using SDK?  Emmm, sorry I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Yes Exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error when I tried the call without encoding the filter parameter. Url need to be properly encoded to filter it. Please encode the whole filter like this

```
$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fl%2Fmeetup-join%2F19%3Ameeting_OTg1YjAxNmYtN2EyZC00YWI0LWI1ZDMtMjVkZDljOTYzMTEz%40thread.v2%2F0%3Fcontext%3D%7B%22Tid%22%3A%22363147dc-b3be-41a7-af56-f673893ef5a7%22%2C%22Oid%22%3A%221ab4e76f-5f52-44b8-8a72-7d03c05e6ff4%22%7D%27
```

Remember one thing, when you get the joinweburl, context parameter is already encoded. So try avoiding it or decode that part and encode the whole url and then apply the call.

You can look into this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp) for Encoding and for Decoding look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c).

Comment: I did that tnx and it's not working it gives me the same error its weird I track the HTTP request and pasted the body to graph explorer it's working there but not in SDK of /net

Comment: @Mobinkh: 
Could you please try to [create a event using online meeting provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#example-create-and-make-meeting-available-as-an-online-meeting)?