# How can I decode and encode m%2Fs to m/s in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some units as "m/s". But, in dotnet I get the value as "m%2Fs". How can I decode and encode it back? I tried using the following but didn't work.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("m%2Fs");
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("m/s");
System.Convert.ToBase64String("m/s");
System.Convert.FromBase64String("m%2Fs");
```

Comment: Where in your application do you get this value? Can you [edit] your post with a [mre]?

Comment: It's a third party application. When I make a call to that API, this is what I get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I decode a URL parameter using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-do-i-decode-a-url-parameter-using-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Web;
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("m%2Fs"));
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(@"m/s"));
```

result

```
m/s
m%2fs
```